# How to pass function to arq worker on python

Tags: python, arq

Run arq worker with some function that have some task to do but getting for below one.
arq import Worker

```
w = Worker(functions=[],
    redis_settings=WorkerSettings.redis_settings(),
    max_jobs=1000,
    keep_result_forever=True,
    job_timeout=86000,
    max_tries=1000)
w.run()
```

Error on missing single function

Comment: Read the docs on [arq.worker.func](https://arq-docs.helpmanual.io/#arq.worker.func).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a function that the worker should run. Otherwise the worker would be quite unnecessary.

For example with the function `the_tasks`, you add it to the `functions` argument of the worker:

```
arq import Worker

async def the_task(ctx):
    print('running the task')
    return 42

w = Worker(functions=[the_task],
    redis_settings=WorkerSettings.redis_settings(),
    max_jobs=1000,
    keep_result_forever=True,
    job_timeout=86000,
    max_tries=1000)
w.run()
```

Maybe start with the demo example: https://arq-docs.helpmanual.io/#simple-usage